# declare an array within a method call in c

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to declare an array within a method call in C?

I currently have:

```
void printConcatLine(char chunks[][20]) {
  for(int x = 0; x < sizeof(chunks); ++x) {
    if(x < (sizeof(chunks) - 1)) {
      Serial.print(chunks[x]);  
    } else {
      Serial.println(chunks[x]);    
    }  
  }
}



 char chunks[][20] = {
    "{", 
    "255"
    "}"
  };

  printConcatLine(chunks);
```

Is there a way to declare the array within the method call instead of declaring it in a variable beforehand?
Something similar to:

```
printConcatLine(["{", "255", "}"]);
```

Comment: Beware that `sizeof (chunks)` no matter how you've passed it to the function evaluates the size of a pointer, ie: `chunks` is a pointer (`void printConcatLine(char chunks[][20]) {...}` is the same as `void printConcatLine(char (*chunks)[20]) {...}`).

Comment: @McWayWeb `a method call in C?` The `Serial.print` strongly suggest you are using C++ in arduino environment. And you may just found out, that C++ and C are __different languages__, and that something works in C it doesn't mean it will work in C++. For example the answer below is perfectly valid C code and at the same time will not work in C++. If you indented to ask about C++, I suggest to accept the answer here and ask a separate question for C++ (even copy the question, just tag it with C++ instead of C).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using [*compound literals*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal):

```
printConcatLine((char [][20]){ "{", "255", "}" });
```

That passes an array of strings to the function.

---

Note that compound literals are a C-only thing, it will not work in C++. And if working on an Arduino the language used *is* C++.

If you're programming in C++ it's simply not possible without modifying the function you call, to either accept a standard C++ container, or possibly an Arduino-specific container.

Comment: The original code passed an array of arrays. So the answer depends on how the function is defined

Comment: I tried using this and it gave me an error: "taking address of temporary array". Does this have to do with how the array is specified in the method call?

Comment: @McWayWeb Updated type for the compound literal so it matches the function declaration.

Comment: @McWayWeb Make sure you are using a C compiler to compile the code.

Answer (score -1):

`````````````````````````
void printConcatLine(char chunks[][20]) {
  for(int x = 0; x < sizeof(chunks); ++x) {
    if(x < (sizeof(chunks) - 1)) {
      Serial.print(chunks[x]);  
    } else {
      Serial.println(chunks[x]);    
    }  
  }
}



 char chunks[][20] = {
    "{", 
    "255"
    "}"
  };

  printConcatLine((char*[]){ "{", "255", "}" });
````````````````````````
`````````````````````````

Comment: Sorry, no, that's invalid. An array of pointers to char can't be accessed using a pointer to an array to 20 chars. Ie. `char**` is not `char (*chunks)[20]` .